# no reason or no reasoning

Tags: word-usage

Which one is correct;

The Employer’s Representative completely rejected granite and terazzo skirting payment items with no clear **reasoning**

The Employer’s Representative completely rejected granite and terazzo skirting payment items with no clear **reason**

Comment: Both are possible, with slightly different meaning.

Answer (score 3):

*Reasoning* is a gerund, derived from the verb *reason* ‘exercise one’s rational ability’. It therefore signifies an act of rationally weighing possibilities and facts.

*Reason* is a noun with a wide range of meanings; in this context it means a ‘cause, motive or explanation’ for an action. This may be based on ‘reasoning’ or it may be a matter of taste or cost or geopolitical contingencies.

*Reasoning* is very unlikely in this context. The writer probably has no means of knowing whether or not the Employer exercised its rational ability; what the writer does know is that the Employer’s Representative did not give a clear **reason** for rejecting the payment items.